# iPhone: quickly quitting an app then relaunching briefly shows last screen then black, then starts fresh

Tags: iphone

Trying to finish up an app I've been developing and have hit an odd bug that I'm not sure if it's on my end? a bug on apple's end?  or perhaps the underpinnings of multitasking showing themselves.

My current app is doing this weird thing when you press the home button to quit the app, and then immediately relaunch the app.  You see the Default.png image as the app starts up, but when it goes to display the window/view it briefly shows the screen as it was just before you quit the app, then goes to black for about 2 seconds and then displays the correct screen as if you were starting up fresh.  I'm see this on all devices, iPods, iPhones, and iPad.

This is not just me, however, I've been trying other apps to see if they do it, and have found that the Air Hockey ( http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/air-hockey/id286106725?mt=8 ) is an example of an app that does this same thing.  My instinct is that there are many apps that do.  But the bulk of apps dont seem to have this issue.

I've done everything I can do make sure all views and view controllers are properly released, but it's almost like the device is taking a while to truly shut down even though the app has visually disappeared, and if you restart the app within probably 3 seconds or less then it still has something in the window buffer, or tht the full on view controller hasn't truly been released yet.

Anybody seen something like this and been able to solve it?

Comment: I'm not seeing it in any of the apps that I opened up.

Comment: Any luck with this issue? I'm seeing the same problem.

Comment: would you happen to be using flurry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the dev of that Air Hockey - It looks like it's probably Flurry that's causing it.  I have a version without Flurry & it doesn't do it.

Comment: It looks like you can solve this by adding this:
[FlurryAPI setSessionReportsOnCloseEnabled:false];

before you call [FlurryAgent onStartSession]

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by updating my Flurry files to the latest version. http://dev.flurry.com/iphone_uploadNewVersion.do